# Html value blank but i assigned it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form which fetches data from a DB and inserts it to a database, some values are inserted blank even though I actually set its values not to be blank and even the browser output shows there is no value to

Here is my code:

```
$search_disease = $_POST['tdisease'];
$disease = "(select * from medications WHERE diagnosis='$search_disease')";
foreach ($pdo->query($disease) as $row){  
    $diagnosis = $row['diagnosis']; 
    $icd = $row['ICD10']; 
}
```

i then echo the results to a select tag

```
<select  style="width: 40%; margin-left: -1%; position: relative;top: -52px; left: 15px;"  name="tdisease">
   <option value="">Select Disease1</option>
   <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo !empty($icd)?$icd:'';?>"><?php echo $row['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
   <?php } ?> 
</select>
<input class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 170px; margin-left: 17%; margin-top: 15%; margin-bottom: 1%; color: #000;" type="submit" name="insertData" value="Create Invoice">
```

And this is what the browser outputs:

```
<select  style="width: 40%; margin-left: -1%; position: relative;top: -52px; left: 15px;"  name="tdisease">
    <option value="">Select Disease1</option>
    <option value="">Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae</option> 
    <option value="">Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor</option> 
    <option value="">Cholera, unspecified</option>                            
</select>
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: does your console shows 'tdisease' value? teh probable reason of it could be check the value attribute of option tag.. It is unassigned....try manually making a select and assign value to all the options and then check if you get a value in  $_POST['tdisease']

Comment: Have you tried `value="<?php echo $row['ICD10'];?>"`?

Comment: are you sure the field with the name ICD10 exists in your database? looks like there is no result on this field

Comment: are you sure that table column ICD10 isn't empty in the database? I see there's no issue on your script, at least for now ...

Comment: the console suprisingly is blank NikitaDhiman

Satpal i will try that
@mtizziani yes tht field is there in my database

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda no its not empty

Comment: @Morena have you tested your query via phpmyadmin (or any db tool you using)?

Comment: yes i have just tested it and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing the diagnosis name but you are not echoing the ICD10 code in the `value` attribute of the `option`.

You should just do this:

`<option value="<?= !empty($row['ICD10'])?$row['ICD10']:'';?>"><?= $row['diagnosis'];?> </option>`

The problem really is that in your `while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))` loop, there is no assignment to the `$icd` variable.

---

OPTION 2:
Change your first php code above to:

```
$diagnoses = [];
foreach ($pdo->query($disease) as $row){ 
  $diagnosis = []; 
  $diagnosis['diagnosis'] = $row['diagnosis']; 
  $diagnosis['icd10'] = $row['ICD10']; 

  $diagnoses[] = $diagnosis;
}
```

Then in the iteration part:

```
<?php foreach ($diagnoses as $disease) { ?>
   <option value="<?= !empty($disease['icd10'])?$disease['icd10']:'';?>"><?= $disease['diagnosis'];?> </option> 
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: but even if that code im still getting a blank value

Comment: Then maybe you don't have a field called `ICD10` in your `medications` table.

Comment: No i have that column

Comment: Run a `describe medications` in your database  and really be sure you're checking the `medications` table and not another table. Also did you modify your code to look like mine?

Comment: Field  Type  Null  Key  Default  Extra  
medicationID  int(11)  NO  PRI  NULL auto_increment
ICD10  varchar(255)  NO   NULL 
diagnosis  varchar(255)  NO   NULL 
NAPPI_CODE  varchar(255)  NO   NULL 
prescription  varchar(255)  NO   NULL 
Price  double  NO   NULL 

thts my table and yes i used the code u typed above

Comment: well now the select tag does not echo anything when i use the second option

Comment: Where did you assign `$result` to an expression?

Comment: $query="SELECT diagnosis FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%$search_disease%'";
                     $result= $con->query($query);

Comment: Then that is where the problem is coming from. You did not select ICD10 from the database table yet you want to show it. Your sql should be something like: `SELECT diagnosis, ICD10 FROM medications WHERE diagnosis LIKE '%$search_disease%'`

Comment: okay thanks this did make a difference,  but instead of echoing $row['ICD10']; as its value i want it to be coming from a variable which is not part of the above query